# Translating raster from GTiff to ASC format using GDAL Python package?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, spyder

I tried using GDAL Translate as follows and encountered an error.

```
OutTileName_tif = CH_14.tif
OutTileName_asc = CH_14.asc

gdal.Translate(OutTileName_tif, OutTileName_asc)
```

Error message is

```
ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.
```

Comment: How are you running GDAL translate? I'm not familiar with that syntax. Are you using Mac or Linux? I use command line and would phase it like GDAL_Translate -of AAIGRID Output/CH_14/model/gis/grids/CH_14.tif Output/CH_14/model/gis/grids/CH_14.asc

Comment: I am using Spyder Python for coding in Windows. I missed specifying format = AAIGrid and reversed the order of inputting the filepaths. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, Spider isn't a package I'm familiar with but it looks like you have an answer anyway. I've added the Spyder tag to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Please try with the following Python snippet.
Need to remember that outputfile path is first, and is followed by the inputfile path.

`gdal.Translate(OutTileName_asc, OutTileName_tif,format='AAIGrid')`